# Theming comments in node.tpl.php

Tags: theming, comments

How can i theming the comments like this in the node.tpl.php (with a new column after 3 comments)? I want to use this:

```
$cols = array();

$cols[] = '<div class="headline">' . t(`Kommentare`) . '</div>';

$comments = comment_render($node, $node->cid);
$comcolnum = 0;

foreach($node-cid as $comcol){
$comcolnum++;
$cols[] = '<div class=description-' . $comcolnum . '">' . $comcol['view'] . '</div>';
}

$cols[] = '<div class="comment-form">' . drupal_get_form('comment_form',array('nid' =>  
$node->nid)) . '</div>';

print theme_table(array(), array($cols))
```

$node->comments, &comments or ... doesn`t work.
I think first i need to override the comment output in the template.php like this for Drupal 6:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
$vars['node']->comment = 0;
$vars['comments'] = $vars['comment_form'] = '';
if (module_exists('comment') && isset($vars['node'])) {
$vars['comments'] = comment_render($vars['node'], $vars['node']->cid);
$vars['comment_form'] = drupal_get_form('comment_form', array('nid' => 
$vars['node']->nid));
}
}
```

But! What i need to get every comment for the foreach function? I`m really new with PHP and Drupal API, but i want to learn it! Can someone show me the right way?

Greeting Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MYTHEME_preprocess_node($vars)` instead of `MYTHEME_preprocess_page($vars)` to get your declared variables in `template.php` to get in `node.tpl.php`.

I see you are already using [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), so just put all those things which are intended for `node.tpl.php` in that function.

Comment: i get everytime the same errormessage:
warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The script for the formfield works perfect:
$cols[] = '<div class="comment-fomr">' . drupal_get_form('comment_form',array('nid' => $node->nid)) . '</div>';

Comment: @Bruno What is output of $node->comments ?

Comment: <?php print $comments ?> give me all the commenst of the node, but i dont know how i can use it for foreach().

    I customised the code now in node.tpl.php to:
    $comments = comment_render($node, $node->cid);
    $comcolnum = 0;

    foreach($node-cid as $comcol){
    $comcolnum++;
    $cols[] = '<div class=description-' . $comcolnum . '">' . $comcol['view'] . '</div>';
}

$cols[] = '<div class="comment-form">' . drupal_get_form('comment_form',array('nid' => $node->nid)) . '</div>';

Comment: @Bruno As I see, you want to theme comments at your node. Why don't your check comment.tpl.php, which get call to generate all the comments at your node. You can override it for particular content type like comment--node-[TYPE_NAME].tpl.php. You can put some more classes/id for each elements & then apply design..
You will find default comment.tpl.php in the $base_url/module/comment folder. Copy that & paste in your theme folder to go further with it..

Comment: Ok, this can be an simpler solution.

Comment: @Bruno - Yes this is. You won't have to go for foreach as TPL will be called each time a comment is generated..